# Cannot download ace using Grunt and shell (Codebox) Permission errors (Virtual Macine)

Tags: node.js, permissions, vagrant, virtualbox, sudo

Working from [Codebox 0.8.1](https://github.com/CodeboxIDE/codebox)

Here is a [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/CrashyBang/dae469973b25c5f7dd13) containing the 3 files that Codebox uses to build its editor addon.

I am on windows running virtualbox ubuntu/precise64 through vagrant in administrative cmd when running npm install all I am fine but when I run `sudo npm start` I receive the following:

```
Building addons in ./addons/ (force=false)
Optimizing cb.files.editor
error for optimization of cb.files.editor
options= { baseUrl: 'addons/cb.files.editor',
  name: 'client',
  out: '/project/addons/cb.files.editor/addon-built.js',
  paths: { 'require-tools': '/project/core/cb.addons/require-tools' },
  optimize: 'uglify',
  map:
   { '*':
      { css: 'require-tools/css/css',
        less: 'require-tools/less/less',
        text: 'require-tools/text/text' } } }
{ [Error: Command failed: node /project/node_modules/requirejs/bin/r.js -o baseUrl=addons/cb.files.editor name=client out=/project/addons/cb.files.editor/addon-built.js paths.requi
re-tools=/project/core/cb.addons/require-tools optimize=uglify map.*.css=require-tools/css/css map.*.less=require-tools/less/less map.*.text=require-tools/text/text  (exited with e
rror code 1)]
  killed: false,
  code: 1,
  signal: null,
  stdout: '\nTracing dependencies for: client\nError: ENOENT, no such file or directory \'/project/addons/cb.files.editor/ace/ace.js\'\nIn module tree:\n    client\n      ace\n\nEr
ror: Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory \'/project/addons/cb.files.editor/ace/ace.js\'\nIn module tree:\n    client\n      ace\n\n    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)\n\n
',
  stderr: '' }
```

If I run `npm start` (no sudo):

```
Running "exec:build_files_editor" (exec) task
>> npm
>> 
>> WARN
>> 
>> package.json
>> cb.files.editor@0.1.1 No repository field.
>> npm
>> 
>> WARN
>> 
>> package.json
>> cb.files.editor@0.1.1 No README data

> cb.files.editor@0.1.1 postinstall /project/addons/cb.files.editor
> ./download_ace.sh && ./build.sh

>> sh: 1:
>> ./download_ace.sh: not found
>> 
>> npm ERR! weird error 127
>> npm
>> WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
>> npm WARN For further explanations, please read
>> /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
>> npm
>> 
>> ERR!
>> 
>> not ok
>> code 0
>> Exited with code: 1.
Warning: Task "exec:build_files_editor" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

Any help would be great?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After breaking the problem down, and trying to execute each shell script individually I found it was a problem with Windows line endings in my Linux VM.

The solution [dos2unix](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/dos2unix1.html) by using this library I was able to convert all the files in the project to LF (Linux) line endings.

After entering the project directory all I had to do was run this command:

```
find . -type f -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Now if I run `npm start` the project compiles correctly.

For any other user encountering this problem I recommend setting up your IDE to default to LF line endings using [EditorConfig.](http://editorconfig.org/)